# Minimal Hosting Model: Exited from Program.Main with exit code = '0'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-minimal-hosting-model

After migrating an ASP.NET Core 6 app from the legacy `Program`/`Startup` to use the [new minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model), I am receiving a non-descript set of errors.

#### Error Messages

I have explicitly enabled `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` to be safe, but all I am receiving in the browser is the generic:

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

In the Event Viewer, Event 1011 gets logged:

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Code' has exited from Program.Main with exit code = '0'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.

Followed by Event 1007:

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\Code' failed to load coreclr.
>
> Exception message:
> CLR worker thread exited prematurely

No further information is available in the debug console when running either IIS Express or Kestrel. I am, however, able to see other startup processes from my `Program` being logged, so know they're loading correctly.

#### Code

This is a simplified version of my `Program` file, with custom components removed:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Should be implicit in Debug mode, but explicitly including to be safe
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();
```

#### Previous Threads

As these are *really* general errors, there are quite a few previous threads available related to this issue—but none that seem applicable to this case. (Many have to do with the [ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-6.0), which I am not using.)

#### Question

Are there common causes for this issue? Alternatively, are there other approaches for debugging this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error messages aren't terribly intuitive, but this error essentially means that the application ran, and then immediately exited. A common cause of this is when you neglect to add the `Run()` command at the end of the `Program`:

```cs
app.Run();
```

#### Background

This is easy to miss if you're focused on migrating your `ConfigureServices()` and `Configure()` methods from your `Startup` class. While most of your previous configuration code likely lives in that class, the `Run()` method is one of a few pieces that needs to be migrated from your legacy `Program` class. You might recognize it from your legacy `Main()` method; e.g.,

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

In the new ASP.NET Core 6 minimal hosting model, this gets translated to:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Configuration from Startup.ConfigureService()

var app = builder.Build();

// Configuration from Startup.Configure()

app.Run();
```

When it exits from `Program.Main()` with exit code `0`, that's telling you that your `Program` ran correctly—and, thus, seeing logging for your configuration code—but then it stopped without ever actually launching your web application.

Simple fix once you know to look for it.

Comment: I found this out myself the hard way. Creating new projects and comparing. NOT easy to spot, but makes all the difference!

Comment: @Heddelin: Yeah! I felt a bit silly posting something so simple. But it’s so easy to overlook and such a confusing error message that I was sure more people would run into it.